# Rails pundit scope does not return from or block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

In my app I want to prevent the user from taking the Legal Test again. To do so I'm using pundit authorization with below policy:

```
class TestResultPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def new?
    !passed? || validation_not_finished?
  end

  private

  def passed?
    user.test_results.where.not(test_result: 'passed').any?
  end
end
```

Which I use in below controller:

```
class TestResultsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :randomize_questions, only: %i[new create]

  def new
    @test_result = TestResult.new
    authorize @test_result
  end

  def create
    #some actions
  end
```

The problem is when user already passed the test he still have ability to take another test (is able to visit `test_results_path`). If I just leave `!passed?` everything will work as it should but if I add OR condition `|| validation_not_finished?` it will make the whole block true instead of return false and skip everything which is after || ?

Answer (score 0):

`||` => Called Logical OR Operator. If any of the two operands are true, then the condition becomes true.

```
> false || false
=> false
> false || true
=> true
> true || false
=> true
> true || true
=> true
```

you can explicitly return `false` when user have failed test, so that it will skip check for `validation_not_finished?`

```
class TestResultPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def new?
    return false if failed?
    validation_not_finished?
  end

  private

  def failed?
    user.test_results.where.not(test_result: 'passed').any?
  end
end
```